# Making a dynamic navigation menu using div class "active" and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a `dynamic navigation bar` (using two div class filters: status private/public/etc.. and type of data audio/video/etc..). 
For now, menu doesn't update according to the active filter item. I just need a JS script that selects in one of the filters the div class "active" and show the id in the other filter. For my example below, I want the prefix "audio" added to the data-filter value instead of "all", and prefix "private" added to the data-filter value instead of "all".

Thus, according to the div class "active", values in the first filter should be:

```
data-filter=".audioall" 
data-filter=".audioprivate" 
data-filter=".audiopublic" 
data-filter=".audiodeleted"
```

and, in the second filter, should be:

```
data-filter=".allprivate" 
data-filter=".audioprivate" 
data-filter=".videoprivate" 
data-filter=".photoprivate" 
data-filter=".newsprivate" 
data-filter=".blogprivate" 
data-filter=".mailprivate" 
data-filter=".socialprivate"
```

My current code:

```
<span class="folder-cat-items">
<div id="all" class="folder-cat-label" data-filter=".allall">all</div> /        
<div id="private" class="folder-cat-label active" data-filter=".allprivate">private</div> / 
<div id="public" class="folder-cat-label" data-filter=".allpublic">public</div> / 
<div id="deleted" class="folder-cat-label" data-filter=".alldeleted">deleted</div>
</span> 

<span class="filter-items">
<div id="all" class="filter-label" data-filter=".allall">all</div> /        
<div id="audio" class="filter-label active" data-filter=".audioall">audio</div> / 
<div id="video" class="filter-label" data-filter=".videoall">video</div> / 
<div id="photo" class="filter-label" data-filter=".photoall">photo</div> / 
<div id="news" class="filter-label" data-filter=".newsall">news</div> / 
<div id="blog" class="filter-label" data-filter=".blogall">blog</div> / 
<div id="mail" class="filter-label" data-filter=".mailall">mail</div> / 
<div id="social" class="filter-label" data-filter=".socialall">social</div>
</span>
```

Here my JS cript regarding brickwall and filters, but it doesn't concern the dynamic data-filter labels..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
            wall.reset({
                selector: '.brick',
                animate: true,
                draggable: true,
                cellW: 160,
                cellH: 160,
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });
            wall.addCustomEvent('onBlockLoad', function(setting){
                console.log(setting);
            });
            wall.filter("");
$(".filter-label").click(function() {
                $(".filter-label").removeClass("active");
                var filter = $(this).addClass('active').data('filter');
                if (filter) {
                    wall.filter(filter);
                } else {
                    wall.unFilter();
                }
$(window).one("scroll",function() { document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop     = 0; });
            });
wall.filter("");
$(".folder-cat-label").click(function() {
                $(".folder-cat-label").removeClass("active");
                var filter = $(this).addClass('active').data('filter');
                if (filter) {
                    wall.filter(filter);
                } else {
                    wall.unFilter();
                }
$(window).one("scroll",function() { document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; });
            });
wall.filter("");
            $(".post-filter-label").click(function() {
                $(".post-filter-label").removeClass("active");
                var filter = $(this).addClass('active').data('filter');
                if (filter) {
                    wall.filter(filter);
                } else {
                    wall.unFilter();
                }
$(window).one("scroll",function() { document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; });
            });
            wall.fitWidth();
        });
    </script>
```

I hope I made myself clear enough. I can specify my question if needed.

Comment: what javascript code do you have until now?

Comment: For now I have none regarding this function. I don't figure how synthax should be and where to put it. I guess it should include getelementsbyid and some php echo function, but i'm not skilfull enough. Thanks for help.

Comment: I updated my question with the brickwall and filters Javascript code, but I don't know if that can help regarding the dynamic filter labels..